# Power BI: Fill gaps between two dates, exclude dates outside range

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

So I am looking to display payments from individual donors over a time period between their first donation, and today's date.

To fill gaps in a visual representation of donations over time, I use a calendar table and select ‘show items with missing data.’

My issue is that if a donor first donated in 2005 the fact that the calendar table starts in 1980 means the graph shows an X axis date range starting that year. So it's showing a lot of time we know has no data.

How can I default the date range to start at the date of the first donation of the user ID passed to the report?

Tables: Calendar, Donations

Comment: Some sample data with expected output will help.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to create a measure that checks to see if there are donations within the current filter context. For your chart this will be for the `date` and `donor` category selections, though this would work in any other filter context that relates to donations.

It will look similar to this:

```
Has Donations =
  if(calculate(isempty(relatedtable(DonationsTable
                                   )
                      )
              )
    ,0
    ,1
    )
```

You can then add this filter to the `Filters on this visual` section of the Filter Pane and check for where the value is `1`, though make sure your `date` axis is set to `continuous`.  This will return all dates between the oldest and newest donation.

Comment: So I notice that if I forget the calendar table and drag the date field in the 'Donations' table into the X axis, and ensure the axis is continuous, Power BI will fill things in well enough. So even if the first donation is some time in 2015 and the last in 2018 there will be space between them when they appear on the axis. But how can I ensure the scale runs to today's date, rather than just the period between the donations?

Comment: That is significantly more complicated and will depend a lot more on how your model is set up.